# Validate cell's value on a custom datagridviewCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a custom `DataGridViewColumn`. The column is hosting a third-party component. I enter edit mode in the cell and modify its value and then I press enter key to validate the value. The problem is that I have to press enter key twice to validate the value. It seems like first enter key is to validate the value in the third-party's editor hosted in the cell, and second one to validate the `DataGridView`'s cell... So how to validate cell's value with only pressing enter key one time?

Also I have seen strange behaviour, for example, the last `DataGridView`'s row does not behaves as the rest of the `DataGridView`'s cells. For last row, if I edit the value of a cell and then press enter key to validate, after validating value, it always remains in the same cell and in edit mode and cell's value gets selected so user can think that cell value is invalid when in fact it isn't. This does not happen with the rest of the rows. They need to press enter key twice to validate and cells do not remain in edit mode after validating.

**EDIT**:
Regarding to the need to press enter key twice:
In the custom cell, when enter key is pressed for first time, it raises the event that says value for the cell has changed, it is in this case, OnSourceValueChanged (this is the event raised for the third-party when value has changed) so into it I do:

```
        this.valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnSourceValueChanged(e);
```

when executed NotifyCurrentCellDirty it raises CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged on datagridview which code is:

```
            if (this.gridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            this.gridView.CurrentCell.DataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            this.gridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
```

After it, DataError event is raised for the datagridview but cell continues in edit mode so I would like to commit the value and exit edit mode. How to do this? Also I have tried:

```
this.dataGridView.CurrentCell.DataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

this.dataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

in DataError handler but it does not work.

Finally, cellvaluechanged is not raised maybe as it is a hosted control in the cell...I don't understand why I have to press enter key twice to commit and validate changes on the cell and exit edit mode for the cell. I want only to press enter key press once.

Maybe the cause is that an error is occurred after commit in CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged. DataError event is raised reporting an commit error. Also, how to avoid commit error? What is happening?

Comment: SendEnter Key in cellvalue changed event is one way. Would you not mind it?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your cell validation logic in CellValueChanged Event. This event will be triggered once the value of the cell is edited.

Comment: How can I handle when enter key is pressed and then when enter key pressed validate the current cell's value programmatically? Maybe with KeyPress event? and why in last row, after validating a cell, it always remains in the same cell?

Comment: Whenever you press enter this CellValueChanged event will be called.

Comment: Please, see my edit post. I explain it more in details what is happening.